# Select a column where value have changed for each row

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to extract data from a MySQL table and insert into another table in a kind of log file format.

let say I have this table.

TableA

```
+--------+----+-------+-------+-------+---------+
|UniqueID|Item|ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC|TimeStamp|
+--------+----+-------+-------+-------+---------+
|1       | 1  | 500   | 600   | 700   |   13:01 |
|2       | 2  |  50   |  60   |  70   |   13:03 |
|3       | 3  |  17   |  18   |  19   |   13:12 |
|4       | 1  | 501   | 600   | 700   |   13:15 |
|5       | 1  | 501   | 600   | 699   |   13:18 |
|6       | 3  |  20   |  18   |  19   |   13:22 |
|7       | 1  | 501   | 600   | 702   |   13:25 |
|8       | 2  |  50   |  66   |  70   |   13:26 |
|9       | 3  |  20   |  25   |  19   |   13:32 |
+--------+----+-------+-------+-------+---------+
```

Ill have multiple table with various number of column and item.
i dont mind hard coding table name and column name.

Id like to end up with this table

```
+----+------+-------+--------+-------------+---------+
|Item|Table |Column |NewValue|PreviousValue|TimeStamp|
+----+------+-------+--------+-------------+---------+
| 1  |TableA|ColumnA| 501    | 500         | 13:15   |
| 1  |TableA|ColumnC| 699    | 700         | 13:18   |
| 3  |TableA|ColumnA|  20    |  17         | 13:22   |
| 1  |TableA|ColumnC| 699    | 702         | 13:25   |
| 2  |TableA|ColumnB|  66    |  60         | 13:26   |
| 3  |TableA|ColumnB|  25    |  18         | 13:32   |
+----+------+-------+--------+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: "I'd like to " isn't a question. What problem are you facing? What have you researched? What have you tried? What is going wrong? This isn't a free write-my-code service - we're here to _help_ you, not just do everything for you.

Comment: I've been googling the whole afternoon to try to achive this. i already build a bunch of query to build my first table. im kinda blocked here not sure where to go next. any help will be appreciated

Comment: Posting the queries you came up with and specific issue(s) you are facing would be helpful

Comment: What kind of programming language are you using to access your database? For Instance .NET along with EMF offers the `ChangeTracker`-Class which will offer anything you need. (Tracking changes is not exactly the task of the Database itself. It's the task of the application using the database for persisting AND tracking changes)

Comment: Im trying to achieve this only using MySql query and or stored Proc. it would be much easier to achive this using an other language. But that process need to be automated.

Comment: and why can't you automate it using another language? All code is potentially automateable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't make this really easy.  You can get the previous record by calculating the previous timestamp and then joining it in.  In MySQL 8.0, you can use `lag()` for this purpose.

Then you need to unpivot the values.  MySQL does not make this really easy, but you can use a `cross join` and `case` expressions.  The rest is simply conditional logic and filtering:

```
select item, 'TableA' as tableName, colname,
       col as newvalue, col_prev as prevvalue, timestamp
from (select t.*, c.colname,
             (case when c.colname = 'columnA' then columnA
                   when c.colname = 'columnB' then columnB
                   when c.colname = 'columnC' then columnC
              end) as col,
             (case when c.colname = 'columnA' then tprev.columnA
                   when c.colname = 'columnB' then tprev.columnB
                   when c.colname = 'columnC' then tprev.columnC
              end) as col_prev
      from (select t.*,
                   (select max(t2.timestamp)
                    from tablea t2
                    where t2.item = t.item and t2.timestamp < t.timestamp
                   ) as timestamp_prev
            from tablea t
           ) t join
           t tprev
           on t.item = tprev.item and t.timestamp_prev = tprev.timestamp cross join
           (select 'columnA' as colname union all
            select 'columnB' as colname union all
            select 'columnC' as colname
           ) c
     ) ct
where col_prev <> col;
```

Comment: Well it took me a while to figure it out but it worked. I've learned so much trying to understand this code. Thanks a lot. I had an issue with the self join subquery "t join t tprev" for some reason my MariaDB could not take it, I ended up running a 2nd query instead. And i ended up with duplicate column name but i,ve fixed it whit that 2nd query.